# Implementing KafkaConnect on EC2 using HDP2.3

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-emr, kafka-producer-api

I am following the steps given in the link http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-build-a-scalable-etl-pipeline-with-kafka-connect to install the kafka -connect on EC2 having HDP2.3 platform.

But I am getting the error :
 *ERROR Failed to flush WorkerSourceTask{id=test-mysql-jdbc-0}, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding messages, 1 left*

Complete error can be seen in the following  :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQwAT.png)

Is this a **kafka issue** or **HDP issue** ?, because i did the same thing on **AWS EMR** and it worked .